# An Update Query with MySQL and JSON

Tags: mysql, json

There is a many-to-many relationship between table `a` and table `b`.  The relationship is stored in the table `a_b`, which has two fields: `a_id`, `b_id`.

For all records in `b` where `group` = 'XYZ', I want to:

1. Find matching records in `a_b`, then ...
2. Insert the corresponding values of `a_id` as a JSON array in `b.my_json`

The first part is easy enough:

```
SELECT * FROM a_b INNER JOIN b ON a_b.b_id = b.id WHERE b.group = 'XYZ'
```

I understand that I need to use an update query, (`update b`), and I probably need to user the `JSON_SET` function, but where do I go from there?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're storing are an array of int ids, you can avoid `JSON_SET` and just use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
UPDATE b as _b
  JOIN (
    ## selecting comma delimited list of ids for a json array
    SELECT
        a_b.b_id,
        CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(a_b.a_id ORDER BY a_b.a_id),']') as json
     FROM a_b JOIN b ON b.id=a_b.b_id 
    WHERE b.group = 'XYZ'
    GROUP BY b.id
  ) AS _a_b ON _a_b.b_id = _b.id
## set those matched a_b and b records w/ group XYZ w/ formed json
SET _b.my_json = _a_b.json
;
```

Basically, we're using table aliases in order to get the grouped ids available for an `UPDATE` statement.

Note: GROUP_CONCAT as a default max length, but you can always increase that if you're concatenating thousands of ids.